# Need to show div after .validate is complete

Tags: jquery

I am using the validate plugin for jQuery and want to show a loading div and hide the submit button after the validation is complete. The next page takes a while to load show I need to show a loading .gif and some text to let the user know what is happening.

I can't do a simple on click show div1 and hide the submit button function because if there is an error then the button is hidden.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: @Reza Only this which isn't correct.    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.loader').show();
              });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `validate` method, there should be an option you can pass to it which is a function to be called when the form is valid.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
      //do stuff after the form is valid
   }
})
```

That is assuming you're using this jQuery validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Yes I am, thanks I'll try this out. Didn't know this function existed, I was searching for it.

Comment: Looks like it works but now the form isn't submitting correctly? Any idea on why this is?

Comment: I tried a couple other things and looliks like this is the correct sequence. 
      submitHandler: function(form) {
 $('#submit_master').hide();
 $('.loader').show();
 form.submit();
        }